# PHP to check If current URL is within Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to use the following code to check if the current URL is within an array.

```
$reactfulPages = array(
    'url-one',
    'url-two',
    'url-three',
);

if (strpos($url, $reactfulPages) == true) {
    echo "URL is inside list";
}
```

I think the way I have set up the array is incorrect as the following code (checking for one URL) works fine..

```
if (strpos($url,'url-one') == true) { // Check if URL contains "landing-page"

}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: ... What? The code is working and it's not suppose to or what?

Comment: @James reactfulPages  is a array so you can't use "strpos($url, $reactfulPages)".str pos use for finding a word or character in a string rather than in array. For finding a url is exist in array you can use method in_array($value,$array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array is fine, the functions to check is not the right way. The `strpos()` function is for checking the string position(s).

The right way to check if something is in your array you can use the `in_array()` function.

```
<?php
$reactfulPages = array(
    'url-one',
    'url-two',
    'url-three',
);

if(in_array($url, $reactfulPages)) {
    echo "The URL is in the array!";
    // Continue
}else{
    echo "The URL doesn't exists in the array.";
}
?>
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The function `strpos()` looks for a substring within a string, and returns the the position of the substring if it is found. That is why your last example works.

If you want to check whether something exists in an array, you should use the `in_array()` function, like so:

```
$reactfulPages = array(
    'url-one',
    'url-two',
    'url-three',
);

if (in_array($url, $reactfulPages) == true) {
    echo "URL is inside list";
}
```

However, since you're comparing URL's, I'm assuming you want to check whether the URL contains one of the strings from the array, not necessarily matching them as a whole.
In this case, you will need to write your own function, which could look like this:

```
function contains_any($string, $substrings) {
    foreach ($substrings as $match) {
        if (strpos($string, $match) >= 0) {
            // A match has been found, return true
            return true;
        }
    }

    // No match has been found, return false
    return false;
}
```

You can then apply this function to your example:

```
$reactfulPages = array(
    'url-one',
    'url-two',
    'url-three',
);

if (contains_any($url, $reactfulPages)) {
    echo "URL is inside list";
}
```

Hope this helps.